# Get FQDN from domain

Tags: selenium, url, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, wget

this is my first question here, so I will try my best.

I am trying to get the protocol and the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) from a bunch of domains, i.e. get `https://es.aliexpress.com` from `aliexpress.com`.
I have tried Selenium webdriver, but it takes too long to compute all the domains (even with short timeouts and blocking images).

I am asking if someone knows a way to do this without loading the content, something like wget but only for the URL.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You must have meant `aliexpress.com` from `https://es.aliexpress.com` ???

Comment: No, just like browsers do, you enter `aliexpress.com` at the nav bar and when you make the get request then in the nav bar appears `https://es.aliexpress.com`

Comment: This still probably isn't the right tool for the job... but you could try a headless browser with selenium so you don't have to go through the UI. It goes quite a bit faster

Comment: Hold on, what is it exactly that you're trying to do? Because what you're asking for isn't the FQDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not really...

First of all, `http` and `https` have nothing to do with domain names. Those are transfer protocols.

Ignoring that part, what you are calling FQDN are often generated at the time you access them.

For instance, many websites redirect the browser from a desktop site to a mobile version (the typical `m.something.com`) based on your User Agent string. Which mean `www.something.com` and `m.something.com` are both valid answers

In the example you gave, aliexpress.com, prepended `es.` which means there is most likely some code on the server that reads in either your location (based on IP address) or a locale setting in your browser to direct you to the `es` version of the website as opposed to the `en` or `dk` version.

These changes can be done via an `.htaccess` file in the root folder of the website, or via back end code.

Google Chrome itself automatically tries to add `www.` if it looks like you typed a URL into the everything bar.

It's also possible that the URL is one giant redirect. Some websites buy up extra domain names that all redirect to their core site. So even if you input `xyz.com` you'll end up at `abcd.com`.

There is no algorithmic way to go from a base URL to what you're calling the FQDN.

---

*P.S. [Here is an article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiuv) about what FQDN means.*

Comment: Okey! Thank you so much for your answer, I will read about it!